# How to make hexagon increase in size?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to know how to increase the size of the hexagon. So far I have the hexagons spaced out, but the hexagons need to increase in size.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq3Ws.png)
Code:

```
import turtle
import math

def drawLine(num, length):
    if num % 2 ==0:
        for x in range (8):
            turtle.forward(15)
            turtle.right(45)
    else:
        for x in range (8):
            turtle.forward (15)
            turtle.right(-45)

def main():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-300,0)
    turtle.speed(5)
    turtle.pensize(2)
    turtle.pendown()


    for x in range (40):
        drawLine(x,20+5*x)
        turtle.forward(20+5*x)
    turtle.hideturtle()

main()
input()
```

Comment: Since you are using Python, presumably you understand that indentation affects the meaning of the code. The code you have posted does not make sense and cannot be run because it is not properly indented. Please post a [mre].

Comment: Please check out and accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK except for one very small detail. The function `drawline(num, length)` takes the parameter `length` and this parameter will be used in functions body, but doesn't. Putting `length` instead of `15` into `turtle.forward( )` results in growing hexagons:

[image]

```
import turtle
import math

def drawLine(num, length):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        for x in range (8):
            turtle.forward(length)
            turtle.right(45)
    else:
        for x in range (8):
            turtle.forward (length)
            turtle.right(-45)

def main():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-300,0)
    turtle.speed(5)
    turtle.pensize(2)
    turtle.pendown()


    for x in range (40):
        drawLine(x, 20+5*x)
        turtle.forward(20+5*x)
    turtle.hideturtle()

main()
```